# What are the Physical Memory Limits on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory Limits for Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/490394/memory-limits-for-windows-8)

What is the maximum amount of RAM (physical memory) that Windows 8(64-bit) can handle?

Is there a way by which we can determine if next generation of RAM is supported by the OS?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about how much memory stick is Supported in Windows 8 64 bit?

Comment: The number of memory sticks (DIMMs) is limited by your motherboard. You probably want to ask how much memory your OS can use.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "next generation of RAM"?

Answer (score 4):

Most 32-bit operating systems can only support 4GB of RAM, because that's the limit of a 32-bit pointer.

Windows 8 x64 can have up to 128 GB of RAM.
Windows 8 Pro and Enterprise x64 can have up to 512 GB.

Comment: Even 32 bit version?

Comment: @Diogo: No; I was getting to that.

Comment: Most 32 bit OS can only to up to 4GB without tricks such as PAE. (This includes windows 8, but not **all 32bit OS's**)

Comment: Sure, just to know, it wasnt me who downvoted you.

Comment: i also need an information like future generations of DDR Ram are supported in Windows 8?will there be any issue?

Comment: 1) That is a different question. Use a new post for that. 2) Do not even ask since it is does not depends on the OS. It depends on the motherboard/chipset and CPU.

Comment: @SLaksNo The downvote was from me since the information was incorrect/incomplete. Now it it is fixed (by a changing a single word) I changed it to an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about RAM limits:

- For 32 bit: 4 GB
- For 64 bit:

  1. Windows 8: 128 GB
  2. Windows 8 Professional: 512 GB
  3. Windows 8 Enterprise: 512 GB

**Source:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Wrong​​​​​​​​​.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 Pro x64 has a limit of 512GB.

[image: Physical Memory Limits Windows 8]

Source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_8

Comment: This answer is not complete.

Comment: @Ramhound Updated the answer.